# What is a word that means "To modify the format of something so that it conforms to a standard?"

Tags: single-word-requests

If I am coding and let's say I decide that for every word I print out, I want to first "change" the format of the words so that they all begin with capital letters. Or, if I want to change the format of a phrase so that there is only a single space between words. Imagine any kind of arbitrary format-changing that doesn't change the data, but does change how it is stored or displayed.

What is the word that describes what I am doing to these words or phrases?

Comment: *Standardise? Regularise? Normalise?*

Comment: To echo FF's suggestions, one definition of **standardize** is _To cause to conform to a standard_, which sounds pretty spot on.  For what it's worth, Wordnik only lists one synonym for _standardize_, and that's _regularize_. (@FF: sorry about the zeds; that's just how we spell 'em over here.)

Comment: Of course *standardise* or *standardize* depends on your location.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not an Oxford man, I see.

Comment: @tchrist: Apparently not! Your comment prompted me to check them out, and I was somewhat mortified to find [standardise](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/standardize?q=standardise) relegated to "also" status under their entry for *standardize*. I'm fine with *dialog, catalog, analog,* etc., but there are limits! (though I graciously accept J.R.'s apologies for unavoidably clunky spelling! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Amusing; I myself don’t care for *catalog/catalogged* compared with *catalogue/catalogued*. But you have to study it a bit to understand [the Oxford position](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_spelling) on preferring *-ize* for (to their mind, sound) etymological reasons. I follow their advice and use *-ize* where appropriate, but that also means I necessarily use *analyse, catalyse, paralyse*, much to the confusion and frustration of my countrymen. I also use *defence* and *offence*, but eschew the French ***u*** that had no basis in Latin and merits none in English.

Comment: @tchrist: I must admit that I view OUP as something of a [snake in the grass](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Is_snake_in_the_grass_an_idiom), lurking in our fine English lawn. The worst of it is even [Chambers](http://www.chambersharrap.co.uk/chambers/features/chref/chref.py/main?title=21st&query=standardise) gives the American spelling before the British one. [O tempora, o mores!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_tempora_o_mores!)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You really shouldn’t think of it as “the American spelling” vs “the British one”, considering that ① it is not historically accurate, and ② it sets up a subconscious knee-jerk rejection for reasons of nationalism. This is the same mind-bug that happens when Americans contrast “English measurements” with “metric ones”, instead of imperial vs standard. By casting it in terms that trigger touchy, emotional chords (and discords)  of lingua mater vs dirty foreignness, they define the discourse in a self-defeating way. **tl;dr** Prejudicial word-choice matters.

Comment: @tchrist: Nah. Tolerance of our brothers across the pond is high here on ELU for those on both sides. Not to mention Canucks, Aussies, etc. You wanna start wars and stuff, you gotta have major disagreements about *religion*, not minor quibbles over orthography.

Answer (score 3):

The word "Format" would work for that, I believe.

"I will format all the strings!"

Comment: +1 Especially in a coding context, `format` is exactly it.

Comment: `format` is probably the best fit. Related to the specification in the question (as a step in the process) `parse` (`reparse`).

Comment: The correct answer is *reformat*, in OP's case

Comment: @Denis That implies wiping data, probably from a hard disk.

Answer (score 2):

Previously-suggested words like *[standardize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/standardize)* and *[normalize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/normalize)* are good, but also consider *[canonicalize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/canonicalize)*, which means (in computing) "to convert data into *[canonical](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/canonical)* form".  (Note that previously-suggested *[format](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/format#Verb)* has a slight advantage; some of its senses agree better with the conditions of your question, *ie*, presenting unchanged data in a different display format.)

Comment: All those are good. I rather like *“render into standard/normal/canonical form”* myself.  One certainly speaks of normalization or canonicalization routines. If you’re a programmer, consider Unicode’s Normalization Form C, which is formed by canonical decomposition followed by composition composition, in that order. Or how you can get the canonical path using the *realpath* function from libc. As words go, I find *canonize* somewhat less unwieldy than *canonicalize*, although I recognize that that might risk invoking unwanted ecclesiastical — or contrapuntal — connotations in some readers.

Comment: @tchrist, I agree, *canonicalize* is clumsy, *canonicalization* still more so.  I think they are suffered only because the phrase "canonical form" is so ... canonical.

Comment: In the software business, the correct answer actually is reformat.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the data is of variable quality and you are pulling the edge cases back into conformity, I would say you are normalizing, standardizing, or cleaning it.

If, instead, you are doing something novel to text that wasn't necessarily aberrant in the first place, such as making everything have an initial capital, that would be modifying, preparing, or processing it.

I mention both cases because the title of your question feels like you're talking about the first case, but your examples feel more like the second.

Comment: At least you aren’t *comformatizing* it. 

Comment: Yeah, *conformalization* is overrated...

Answer (score 0):

In a software development context, the correct answers are:

- "reformat", if you're merely changing spaces and case, and adding comments here and there.
- "refactor", if you're also moving code around, e.g. shifting bits and pieces in subfunctions, etc.

It's "re-" in both cases because the code already exists. You "format" your code when you write it, and "reformat" existing code when you maintain it.

Answer (score -1):

*Rectify*. Which is to imply previous behavior was incorrect.